# Play template project requires subscription to typesafe, why?

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I'm using Play Framework to create a quick web app. I took template `play-java-intro-reactive-platform-15v01`, created a new app and when I want to run `$ activator test` I get an error:

> [error] == Typesafe Reactive Platform: project/typesafe.properties must exist with typesafe.subscription=< YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID >.

Why? Is it possible to use the template without creating a subscription?

Comment: https://github.com/typesafehub/ReactiveMaps/issues/25#issuecomment-69457282

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the templates with the `reactive-platform-$version` suffix.

So instead of `play-java-intro-reactive-platform-15v01`, just use the `play-java-intro` template.